# Display group's first element as parent

Tags: php, postgresql

I have this query:

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY code, company, status ORDER BY company LIMIT 15`

I want to display group's first element as parent and other as child, like:

```
Company Name 1
-- Compnay Name 1 | Code | Status 
-- Company Name 2 | Code | Status

Company Name 3
--Company Name 3 | Code | Status

Company Name 4
--Company Name 4 | Code | Status
--Company Name 5 | Code | Status
```

Also there should limit of 15 parents. Please let me how to loop though this to output like this using PHP (DB is PGSQL)?

Comment: Not sure how to loop through to get such output?

Comment: How do you decide which element is a parent and which isn't?

Comment: @nkr first element of the group

Comment: It's very likely you can use row_number() to get solution you want. Can't give more precise solution until I know how do you put rows into groups. I'd say best way to get answer very fast would be to create toy example with input and desired output (on sqlfiddle.com would be even nicer)

Comment: @RomanPekar I'm not looking for row number. I want to display result group wise . Company Name 1 , 2 should be considered as individual company name not row number. thanks!

Comment: @aryankumar simple question - how do you decide Company Name 1 and Company Name 2 goes into first group? and again - ADD SIMPLE EXAMPLE of your daata and desired output

Comment: @RomanPekar I'm grouping data by company name, code, status. first company name from a grouped data can be displayed. I know groups are not like nested array but we can think like it

Comment: can anyone let me know how to put a <br> after each group (notice being grouped by multiple cols)? I would be able to resolve above query if you can help with this one